# Storing integer as string in firebase realtime databse

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there anyway to store a date string 1/1/2017 as a key in a node in `firebase realtime database`?

It create nested nodes with keys like 1->1->2->0->1->7. What i want is 1_1_2017->(Other data nodes)

Comment: Slashes in Firebase represent children paths. I think you're getting 1->1->2017 instead

Comment: Sounds like you just want to replace slashes with underscores

`"1/1/2017".replace("/","_")`

Comment: hey -> means new level of nested nodes

Comment: I understood that. The 2017 isn't broken apart. At least shouldn't be

Comment: my bad... its not broken apart

Answer (score 0):

Convert date into long and concatanate it with "" to cast long to String. When you need the date back Long.parseLong(String) will parse it long and you can convert it back to date again with Date and SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: can you please provide me with some code for that? i did not understand what u tried to say

Comment: @SHIKHAR this answer is saying use Long data types, not strings in Firebase. Only convert the longs to formatted dates when you actually need them to be displayed

Comment: @cricket_007, yes, you are right. I wrote the concatenation if it's strictly needed to save as Strings. Saving dates as long makes them easier to sort or compare. However, it depends how you prefer to store your values, both answers are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model class with String date  as member , for storing in firebase create object set string time and push that object to firebase , i am doing like that it is working

Comment: gve me your code then, coz i  did and its still all same

Comment: ChatroomInfo chatroomInfo = new ChatroomInfo(); // this is model class

 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

 chatroomInfo.setCreatedTime(formattedDate);

Comment: and push that object